# Visualization of consecutive durations between two groups

Tags: r, data-visualization

#### **Summary:**

How can I effectively visualize the variability in the time to complete consecutive tasks between two groups?

#### **Background:**

I am performing a health outcome study for how long it takes for three particular tasks to be completed for individuals in two study groups. I hypothesize that tasks may take longer for one of the two groups.

[image: Tasks]

As diagrammed above, one or more tasks are assigned for individuals on a specific date. Each task has exactly 3 subtasks.

For each individual / task combination, varying amounts of time will have elapsed since the task was assigned. Zero to three of the subtasks will have been completed as of the date of analysis.

### **Sample Data:**

The data are similar to this example data:

```
Individual Group  Task    Event Time Cumulative
         1     A Task1   Assign    0          0
         1     A Task1 Subtask1  508        508
         1     A Task1 Subtask2   37        541
         1     A Task1 Subtask3   10        548
         1     A Task1  Elapsed   NA         NA
         1     A Task2   Assign    0          0
         1     A Task2 Subtask1  507        507
         1     A Task2 Subtask2   28        532
         1     A Task2 Subtask3   20        547
         1     A Task2  Elapsed   NA         NA
         2     A Task2   Assign    0          0
         2     A Task2 Subtask1    0          0
         2     A Task2 Subtask2   26         26
         2     A Task2 Subtask3    6         32
         2     A Task2  Elapsed   NA         NA
         3     B Task2   Assign    0          0
         3     B Task2 Subtask1   NA         NA
         3     B Task2 Subtask2   NA         NA
         3     B Task2 Subtask3   NA         NA
         3     B Task2  Elapsed  274        274
```

A much larger set of example data is available [in tabular form here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ianmcampbell/75eba39cd469ae741005f0d7d1d9434f/raw/c182db1f2d143f05ba6986c87b456ff2ffdff232/SampleData.tsv) or [R `dput` here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ianmcampbell/d6723a6a56a647e37a565268d9c9c1f4/raw/12aa53717d965fe0248724faf04bf17abab46abb/SampleData.R).

#### I am struggling to come up with the best way to visualize the data.

### **Survival Plot:**

One approach I tried was similar to a survival analysis. Reproducible R code [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ianmcampbell/d167115b210392815ed31d023aec07cf/raw/fd065f1ebe455331ec88cf294e2df445e1c0c9ac/SamplePlots.R).
[image: Survival Plot]

It is clear that the two groups differ in the speed of completion of subtask 1, and almost everyone who starts subtask 2 completes it. The concept of sensoring is much more intuitive in this representation. However, it loses the within-individual effect among subtasks. Additionally, it does not really show what fraction of tasks have been fully completed.

### **Bar Plot:**

Another approach I attempted was a bar plot. Reproducible R code [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ianmcampbell/d167115b210392815ed31d023aec07cf/raw/fd065f1ebe455331ec88cf294e2df445e1c0c9ac/SamplePlots.R). On the (now) y-axis is the individual, and on the x-axis is the time elapsed since assignment. The color of the bar indicates the duration of each subtask. The bars in each facet are ordered according to total task completion time or total elapsed time.
[image: Barplot]

In this version, it is much more clear which tasks have been fully completed. It is also more apparent the number of individuals in each group / task combination. However, it is much more difficult to compare between groups and sensoring is much less intuitive. Finally, although the sample data has a couple hundred individuals, the actual dataset has an order of magnitude more individuals, making the bars too small to actually see. Thus, a sampling procedure would be needed.

### **Mirrored Histogram:**

Finally, I attempted some mirrored histograms. Reproducible R code [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ianmcampbell/d167115b210392815ed31d023aec07cf/raw/fd065f1ebe455331ec88cf294e2df445e1c0c9ac/SamplePlots.R).

[image: Histogram]

This representation potentially makes it possible to compare between the two groups for a specific task (but likely not as well as the survival plots). It may be less intuitive because of the negative values for group B. Also, density is a harder concept for broad audiences.

### **Question:**

#### Is there a more effective way to visualize consecutive task duration data to compare two groups?

I found [Visualizing duration time estimates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315207/visualizing-duration-time-estimates), but it focuses on a single task duration. I also found [this Q&A](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/86059/appropriate-visualization-for-this-kind-of-data) over on DataScience.SE, but there was no answer.